# Resolving paths in a custom root directory and avoiding going in parent folders

Tags: node.js, path

Using `path.resolve` we can resolve paths using Node.js.

I want to have a directory containing files and other directories and so on. From the client I receive a path as string and I have to resolve it in this directory.

Because of security, I have to prevent the result path to be outside of the directory:

```
// This comes from the client
let filePath = "/../../../some-sensitive-data-from/disk";

/* Here I have to check if the path is inside of the directory */

path.resolve(ABSOLUTE_PATH_TO_MY_DIR + filePath);
```

How to prevent the access to parent directories of `ABSOLUTE_PATH_TO_MY_DIR`?

Obviously a solution would be to check if the final path is still inside of the `ABSOLUTE_PATH_TO_MY_DIR` path. But maybe there are other better solutions.

Comment: How would a different solution be better than a simple solution that's good?

Comment: @Amit I'm wondering if there is a *standard way* or *good practice* for doing this. I lived with this question for years. :-)

Comment: BTW, a truly better solution would be to **never accept user input to traverse a sensitive resource**.

Comment: Can you exemplify a scenario where accepting such input is required?

Comment: @Amit I want the user to input a file name (or path) and an optional password (if there is one) to download a file from a directory containing the files.

Comment: And the user is supposed to guess the file name (or path)? Probably not, and that's the point of my objection... The service lists the files, so the user doesn't need to send path strings, just IDs

Comment: @Amit Well, they can guess is by brute force (as long I don't handle such attacks), but usually no, they will know the filename.

Comment: I don't know if you noticed, I edited my comment when you posted your reply... Unless I misunderstand the use case, the solution is not in handling the path, it's in not accepting a path input altogether...